# How to do long press in Ionic v1?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am writing an app with AngularJS v 1.5.3 and Ionic v 1.3.5.

I want to do a long press on an html element.
I have looked through the docs here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/
and I could not find any info about this.

Is it possible to do a long press in Ionic v1 or in AngularJS?

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the docs:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/utility/ionic.EventController/

```
onGesture(eventType, callback, element, options)(alias: ionic.onGesture)
```

eventType: `hold`

Comment: `<div on-hold="holdFunc()">example</div>` and just have a function named `holdFunc()`with this example

Comment: can you use on-click and on-hold on the same element?

Comment: Yes, that is possible.